# Deleting artifacts older than 2 years from local nexus repository

Tags: nexus

We're running nexus on some old hardware which is limited in disk space and would like to remove artifacts older than a certain threshold.

Is there any way to do this other than a combination of find and [curl](http://parkerwy.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/curl-safely-delete-artifacts-from-nexus/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned on a [Sonatype blog post linked](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published) from a comment in the blog in gavenkoa's answer, since Nexus 2.5 there is a built in "Remove Releases From Repository" scheduled task which can be configured to delete old releases keeping a defined number.

This is sufficient to meet our needs.

Comment: @Freedman I agree that build-in functionality better then hand written (especially if repository layout changed in future Nexus versions). +1

Answer (score 8):

There is a scheduled task that can automatically remove old snapshot releases:

- http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/09/nexus-scheduled-tasks/
- http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html

Unfortunately, this does not work for hosted release repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all files to which no one access more then 100 days and not modified more then 200 days:

```
find . -type f -atime +100 -mtime 200 -delete
```

To cleanup empty directories:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Or alternatively look to https://github.com/akquinet/nexus_cleaner/blob/master/nexus_clean.sh and corresponding blog entry http://blog.akquinet.de/2013/12/09/how-to-clean-your-nexus-release-repositories/ (delete all except last 10 releases).

Comment: Hello, where exactly should these 2 find commands be executed? I mean... I have my /nexus-data folder mounted in root but there are many subfolders in it and I think it's dangerous to delete every unused file there.

Comment: @icordoba Have you looked at https://github.com/akquinet/nexus_cleaner ? If Nexus changed its storage format to some binary form - you are out of lack.

Comment: Thanks. I finally solved my problem using this groovy script: https://github.com/xninjaxelitex/nexus3-cleanup-release-artifact

Comment: you CANNOT just remove files from a nexus node using "find" like the above.   It will corrupt the data and cause linking issues for the database.

Comment: Nexus has "repair indexes". You need to restart it and trigger repair.

Answer (score 0):

auto purge older than 30 days(u can change it) not download docker images from nexus 3

https://gist.github.com/anjia0532/4a7fee95fd28d17f67412f48695bb6de

```
# nexus3's username and pwd
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin123'

# nexus host
nexusHost = 'http://localhost:8081'

# purge repo
repoName = 'docker'

# older than days
days = 30

#change and run it
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nexus2, you can use my Spring Boot application https://github.com/vernetto/nexusclean , you can define rules based on date and on a minimum number of Artifacts to retain, and it generates "rm -rf" commands (using the REST API is damn slow).

For Nexus3, I would definitely use a Groovy script as a "Execute Admin Task". One is posted here [groovy script to delete artifacts on nexus 3 (not nexus 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589937/groovy-script-to-delete-artifacts-on-nexus-3-not-nexus-2)